# POS tagger and chunker

Tags: machine-learning, pos-tagger

I want to make a POS tagger and chunker using JAVA. But I am unable to figure out that from where should I start. What all libraries would be required?

Answer (score 1):

you can use various libraries

- [Stanford Core NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)
- [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)
- [Gate](https://gate.ac.uk/gate/doc/plugins.html)

I used OpenNLP in my project. I think this instructions will help you to go through OpenNLP Library. Follow this [document](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html)

1. First download the models from this [page](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/)
2. Then add those into your project
3. You also need `Tokenizer` model to break sentences into tokens. Then pass these tokens into POS Tagger.

Code Samples

---

**Load Model**

```
InputStream modelIn = null;

try {
  modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-pos-maxent.bin");
  POSModel model = new POSModel(modelIn);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  // Model loading failed, handle the error
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  if (modelIn != null) {
    try {
      modelIn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Instantiate POSTaggerME**

```
POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);
```

---

**Generate TAGS**

```
    String sent[] = new String[]{"Most", "large", "cities", "in", "the", "US", "had",
                                 "morning", "and", "afternoon", "newspapers", "."};
//This is manual String tokens of a sentence. To Generate word token use [Tokenizer Model][6]         
    String tags[] = tagger.tag(sent);
```

Links

- Implement [Tokenizer Model](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer)
- Implement [Chunker](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.chunker)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read articles or reports to know what they did. I' m working with Vietnamese processing, not know what libraries use in English. But I saw Stanford nlp while using Vietnamese tagger libraries.
I think grammar and lexicon are very important. 
This is NLP Stanford, try this. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml